# angular change element height on screen change in width or height

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that will listen to change in screen size (width or height) and will change my element height.

the purpose is that i want my element to expand until the end of the browser window.

this is my directive:

```
.directive('strechToBottom', ['$document', '$window', function ($document, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

            var space;

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return $window.innerHeight;
            }, function () {
                space = $window.innerHeight - element[0].offsetTop;
                element.css('min-height', space + "px");
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

When the element is created the function gets called and everything is ok.
The problem is that when i change my screen size the function doesn't get called, it does get called after a while, as if it takes time until the function gets called in the cycle or something i can't understand.

i tried to also listen to innerWidth but that didn't work as well.

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/SfJ8c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding to all scope digests, as you're doing by passing a function to `$scope.$watch` as the first argument, makes the function execute in a non-deterministic manner (from your point of view). Basically, it will only execute on some form of interaction with the application (this is not really accurate but it's a good first approximation).

To do something when the viewport is resized, use the native `resize` event:

```
angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        // ... perform your magic here
    });
});
```

---

If the above doesn't really inform you of everything you consider a resize, you could instead do what you're currently doing and just also trigger a `$digest()` on window resize:

```
angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

However, you should be wary of the performance implications of binding functions to be executed on every digest.